# Postgres timestamp not accepting 2017-01-01T23:00:00-00:00

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

Working in Jupyter with Python3 and psycopg2 to load csv into psql. First two columns are an ISO format I'm not too familiar with. Is there a simple data type that will accept:

```
2017-01-01T23:00:00-00:00
```

I've tried date, timestamp, timestamp w/o timezone, timestamp w/timezone. Do I need to pre-process in order to convert timestamp to friendlier format?

I thought I could do something like -

```
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE test(
id integer PRIMARY KEY,
intervalbegin_gmt timestamp,
intervalend_gmt timestamp, ...
```

Getting error -

```
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "2017-01-01T23:00:00-00:00"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is a proper timestamp input literal:

```
select '2017-01-01T23:00:00-00:00'::timestamp

      timestamp      
---------------------
 2017-01-01 23:00:00
(1 row)
```

The problem is that you are trying to import the column into the integer column `id`.

> First two columns are an ISO format ...

so the table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    intervalbegin_gmt timestamp,
    intervalend_gmt timestamp, 
    ...
```

You can add the primary key, if you need it, after copying the data.

Comment: Awesome, moved primary key to the end. Worked like a charm!